# XslCompiledTransform fails with stack overflow

Tags: xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have a large XSLT file with 805 templates that, depending on the system and environment, fails with a stack overflow.

The development environment is Windows 7, InfoPath 2010 and C#.  Although .NET 4.0 is installed, this version of InfoPath uses .NET 2.0.

The routine being used is:

```
private void TransformXML(String inputFileName, String transformFileName, String outputFileName)
{
    CorralLog(String.Concat("Transform with ", transformFileName, ": ", inputFileName, " -> ", outputFileName));

    using (XmlReader inputFile = XmlReader.Create(inputFileName, null))
    {
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
        XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, false);

        transform.Load(transformFileName, settings, null);

        using(XmlWriter outputFile = XmlWriter.Create(outputFileName))
        {
            filesToDelete.Add(outputFileName);
            transform.Transform(inputFile, outputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

I can see some possibilities:

1. Increase the memory available to the 'transform.Load' command
2. Start a separate thread with more memory
3. Start a separate thread and execute the transform with 'msxsl.exe' (which always works)
4. Split up the XSLT file into smaller pieces and do a transformation multiple times

Does anyone have advice on which option to choose?  Or any other suggestions?

Paul

---

The XLST file in question takes some elements from an XML file, changes the name for some elements, and produces another XML file.  There are about 800 elements, each with its own template.

This code shows the three templates at the beginning of the XSLT file and two templates for copying elements:  one for copying an element as is, and the other changing the name of the element.  All subsequent templates are formatted in one of these two ways.

Is this syntax is causing recursion, or is the number of templates causing the stack overflow.  (We have avoided the problem, but perhaps not solved it, by running this transform in a new thread.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-03-16T10:53:27">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SAN/ClientProfiles/ClientProfile">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SAN/ClientProfiles/ClientProfile/Name">
        <CompanyName>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </CompanyName>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: LOTS of information missing.  Under what specific conditions does it fail? Have you tried anything yourself yet (if not, why not)? If you give it enough memory (say 12GB) does it always run successfully?  With the information given so far any answers will be wild guesses.

Comment: Not sure why you're saying that "do a transformation multiple times" goes with "Split up the XSLT file into smaller pieces." Is it a multi-stage transformation?

Comment: We already have five transforms because of the different types of work being done in each.  So making the large one smaller might help, doing it in more than one transform.  But we seem to have had success in throwing the transform out to a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

See whether the suggestions in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-5-something-went-really-wrong-outofmemoryexception-and-stackoverflowexception-thrown-when-using-xslcompiledtransform.aspx help avoid the problem.

Comment: The MSDN article is excellent.  Although we are not using the specific constructs mentioned, the point is well-taken that most of the stack overflow problems can be solved by changing the XSLT file.

In our case, we have started a new thread to do the transform and this appears to work.  In the long term, changing the XSLT, if possible, would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the reference. It shows that the devil's in the detail; I certainly wouldn't have expected that simply having thousands of template rules could be enough to cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of a stack overflow is deep recursion in your XSLT code. I would take a look at the relevant templates and see if they can be written some other way, e.g. to use divide-and-conquer recursion rather than head-tail recursion, or perhaps to take advantage of XSLT 2.0 - there are a couple of good XSLT 2.0 processors for .NET.

Comment: I hope there's not recursion in the XSLT code.  Because we're taking only some elements from the source XML, we have 805 templates which just copy that element to the destination XML.  Would that large number of templates cause recursion?

Comment: who knows? Michael Kay is correct in his statement upfront. You have not provided one bit of your XSL to even diagnose and yet your thought for solution is asking about increasing memory and such ... your XSLT is the problem more than likely and yet you presented none of it to ask others to evaluate possible issues

Comment: I didn't post XSLT code at first because I thought it was a Windows or .NET problem.  Given that the cause might be a mis-design of the XSLT file, I've added XSLT code to my question.